# sendMessage fails both directions Apple Watch <-> iPhone in simulator

Tags: ios, iphone, apple-watch

I'm building an iPhone/Apple Watch app. Following [a tutorial online](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/watchos-2-communicating-with-a-counterpart--cms-24372), I wrote some code to set up a session variable both in the iOS side (via viewDidLoad() in the ViewController) and on the watch side (via willActivate() in the InterfaceController.

When I run the app/s in the simulator, sending a message from the watch to the phone yields:

> Error Domain=WCErrorDomain Code=7005 "Device is not paired." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Device is not paired., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Pair the device with a Watch.}

While sending a message from the phone to the watch yields:

> Error Domain=WCErrorDomain Code=7006 "Watch app is not installed." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Watch app is not installed., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Install the Watch app.}

The problem is that the simulator reports that the simulator devices are both paired, so error 7005 seems wrong, and the watch app is obviously installed because I can see it in the Watch app on the phone, so error 7006 seems wrong. Neither of these errors make any sense, and Xcode's simulators are so fickle I can't tell where the problem in the chain might be. Can anyone offer any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I seem to run into this problem (Watch app is not installed) frequently especially when I build different versions of my app, when I do sendMessage.

Im using Xcode 7.2.1 and I go into the Apple Watch app on the phone and find your app and Switch off/on: "Show App on Apple Watch", then rebuild